# What is AWS Resource Id of an ECS Service

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-auto-scaling

I am trying to define a `CustomizedMetricSpecification` for an ECS Service using `put-scaling-policy` CLI command.

The command requires the `resource-id` of the scalable target which auto-scaling service will scale but I am not able to find the resource-id of my ECS Service.

I tried to pass the ARN of the service as `resource-id` but I am getting this error.

`An error occurred (ObjectNotFoundException) when calling the PutScalingPolicy operation: No scalable target registered for service namespace: ecs, resource ID: arn:aws:ecs:us-east-1:XXXXXXXXXXXX:service/XYZ-SERVICE, scalable dimension: ecs:service:DesiredCount`

CLI Command:
`aws application-autoscaling put-scaling-policy --service-namespace ecs --scalable-dimension ecs:service:DesiredCount --resource-id arn:aws:ecs:us-east-1:XXXXXXXXXXXX:service/XYZ-SERVICE --policy-name custom-scaling-policy --policy-type TargetTrackingScaling --target-tracking-scaling-policy-configuration file://custom_autoscaling_config.json`

Is ARN not the correct value for resource-id field? What should I do to create the custom auto-scaling policy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see the documentation for this [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/application/userguide/services-that-can-integrate-ecs.html), along with an example. The expected format of the resource ID is not obvious at all. You would never know the format without finding that documentation. The expected format is a string like this:

`"service/cluster-name/service-name"`

Where `service` is the hard-coded literal string "service", `cluster-name` is the name of your ECS cluster, and `service-name` is the name of your ECS service.